# Is this the correct parseTree for a SQL join statement?

Tags: sql, parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I have written the following pared-down example to verify that the parse tree for the SQL `FROM` clause is correct. Particularly, that doing something like `tbl1 JOIN tbl2 JOIN tbl3 JOIN ...` is done correctly. Here is the grammar I currently have:

```
grammar Associativity1;
root: (select ';')* EOF;

select
    : 'SELECT' expr (',' expr)*
       ('FROM' tblExpr)?
    ;

expr
    : '(' expr ')'
    | subSelect
    | expr '=' expr
    | Atom
    ;

tblExpr
    : subSelect
    | tblExpr 'JOIN' tblExpr 'ON' expr
    | Atom
    ;

subSelect:
    '(' select ')'
    ;

Atom: [a-zA-Z]+ | [0-9]+;
WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

And the parse tree from the following statement (using the `AAA`'s so easier to recognize from the parseTree:

```
SELECT 1
FROM (SELECT AAAAAAAAAA) 
JOIN (SELECT BBBBBBBBBB) ON (1=2) 
JOIN (SELECT CCCCCCCCCC) ON (2=3) 
JOIN (SELECT DDDDDDDDDD) ON (4=3);
```

[image]

If I am interpreting it correctly it is evaluating it as (feel like I'm writing lisp...):

```
# First join AAA to BBB.
# Join that result to CCC
# Join that result to DDD
JOIN(
  JOIN(
    JOIN(
      TblExpr(AAA), 
      TblExpr(BBB)),
     TblExpr(CCC)),
   TblExpr(DDD)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you interpretation is an accurate understanding of the parse tree.

Since SQL is a declarative language, I don't suppose there's any *guarantee* that the sql engine would actually execute the joins in that order, though it should guarantee the same result.